# Should I place user image uploads to Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, amazon-web-services, upload, amazon-s3

Imagine a website like Craigslist.

Users can create a "For Sale" listing and attach images of what they're trying to sell.

Should I upload these images to Amazon S3 or something like Amazon Cloud instead?

Answer (score 1):

S3 is the perfect place for storing those.  Users can upload to your app, which does any validation needed, then transfers to an S3 bucket.  Permissions can be managed via IAM roles assigned to your instance(s).

To serve them to your users, you will probably want to use CloudFront - at higher usage it can be cheaper and faster than serving directly from S3

Comment: How cloudfront+S3 cheaper than S3 only? Is there any reference?

Comment: Check S3 and Cloudfront pricing - first 10TB is $0.12/GB, but Cloudfront drop a bit quicker than S3 after than.  At < 10TB/month, costs will be similar.

Comment: Notice request pricing! cloudfront is $0.0075, and S3 is $0.004. You may get pricing benefit by using cloudfront only when serving large file. (less requests, more transfer out)